# How to catch values from controller to library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I have a library that requires a constant value from a controller. I want to catch those values "customer_id" and "date_preset" from a  controller to supply them in my library.
This is my Library.

```
class GoogleAdsCustomerInfoLib {

    private const CUSTOMER_ID = $customer_id; //need to catch the value from here
    private const DATE_PRESET = $date_preset; //need to catch the value from here

    public static function customer() {

     //some more codes here
     
    }
}
```

This is a method from my controller

```
public function customer(){

            $data = array(
                'customer_id' => '123456789',
                'date_preset' => 'LAST_7_DAYS'
            );

            $customer = $this->googleadscustomerinfolib->customer();

           return $customer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of a CONSTANT, as its name suggests.

You must then pass the values from your controller to your library using standard properties (declared public, or via a setter).

For example you lib :

```
class GoogleAdsCustomerInfoLib {

    public $customer_id; 
    public $date_preset; 

    public static function getCustomer() {

     //some more codes here
     //you can here access $this->customer_id and $this->date_preset
     
    }
}
```

and your controller:

```
public function getCustomerCompleted(){

            $customer = new GoogleAdsCustomerInfoLib();
            $customer->customer_id = 1234567;
            $customer->date_preset = 'LAST_7_DAYS';
            $customer = googleadscustomerinfolib->getCustomer();

           return $customer;
}
```

Another way to do it is to call your lib function with given parameters, like this :

```
class GoogleAdsCustomerInfoLib {

    public static function getCustomer($customer_id, $date_preset) {

     //some more codes here
     //you can here access $customer_id and $date_preset

    }
}
```

and use it in your controller like this :

```
public function getCustomerCompleted(){

            $customer = new GoogleAdsCustomerInfoLib();
            $customer = googleadscustomerinfolib->getCustomer(12456,'LAST_7_DAYS');
           return $customer;

}
```